# Adding removing input fields using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am adding input field on clicking the button and at the same time giving remove button to remove the input field.However my remove button is not removing the input field instead it takes me to top of page...

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Preferred Work Location</label>
<div class="col-md-3">
<input type="text" id="loc" name="Work_Location[]" class="form-control" >
</div>
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Locations</button>
</div>
</div>
```

and below is the jQuery to add more textbox when I click the button

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Preferred Work Location</label><div class="col-md-3"> <input type="text" id="loc" name="Work_Location[]" class="form-control"  ></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ta0ya1Lw/1/ - looks fine

Comment: it works fine as in the fiddel : http://jsfiddle.net/Dimal_Chandrasiri/0mthepy7/

Comment: change `href="#"` to `href="javascript:;"`

Comment: works fine on codepen too

Comment: BTW, `wrapper` is already a jQuery object, there's no need to write `$(wrapper)`.

Comment: ⇑⇑⇑ And `add_button` too. And FYI, IDs must be unique on document context, your code is asking for trouble

Comment: but in mine its not working..it just takes me to top of page when i click remove button and a '#' sign comes in link

Comment: did you try `href="javascript:;"`?

Comment: Jquery's on() is supported from version 1.7 so make sure your version >= 1.7

Comment: @Learner href="javascript:;" worked but now it reloads the page when i click remove button..I dont want the page to reload

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/zoo6u8jd/2/ try this code

Comment: @Learner Not working...I click remove button and nothing happens

Comment: then there is another issue check error console code is fine

Answer (score 4):

I have an example for you, you can do it easier

```js
function closeMe(element) {
  $(element).parent().remove();
}

function addMore() {
  var container = $('#list');
  var item = container.find('.default').clone();
  item.removeClass('default');
  //add anything you like to item, ex: item.addClass('abc')....
  item.appendTo(container).show();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
    <li class="default" style="display: none;">
        <input type="text" /><span style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="closeMe(this);">close</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<button onclick="addMore();">Add</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
   
    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });
   
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this is helpful for you

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max = 10;
    var wrp= $(".input_fields_wrap");
    var addBtn = $(".add_field_button");

    var x = 1;
    $(addBtn ).click(function(e){ 
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max){ 
            x++;
            $(wrp).append('<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="example-text-input">Preferred Work Location</label>
<div class="col-md-3"> 
<input type="text" id="loc" name="Work_Location[]" class="form-control"  >
</div>
<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
        }
    });

    $(wrp).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ /
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Comment: So what was the issue in his code and why this code will work? can you please explain a bit?