# Validating input text fields created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The following code was obtained from:

[Adding removing input fields using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31603667/adding-removing-input-fields-using-jquery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

Given that an unknown number of inputs with the name **mytext[]** will be created: How could I validate that none of them are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be helpful for you. Please adapt the following code in click event (example):

When you click remove_field element the following loop function will be execute.

**

```
$("input:text").each(function()
{
   if($(this).value==''){
    console.log('error');
   }
});
```

**

Full Example:

```
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
        $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e)
  { //user click on remove text
    $("input:text").each(function()
    {
      if($(this).value == ''){
        console.log('error');
      }
    });

    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
  });

  });


</script>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

You will get the value of current loop element in $(this).value.